# Is it reasonable and supported to update cc-mode to latest, without updating emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have emacs 22.2.1.  Is it safe, or even recommended, to update [cc-mode](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/) to the latest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/release.php for the cc-mode maintainer's position on this.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: [Damyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695717/is-it-reasonable-and-supported-to-update-cc-mode-to-latest-without-updating-emac/2698782#2698782) is much more informative.**

No. The [cc-mode the sourceforge project](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/) made its last release on February 2006, well before Emacs 22.2. Currently cc-mode is bundled with Emacs, so the only way to upgrade would be to take the related elisp sources from newer Emacs and backport them yourself.